# How to use Uri.parse in android

Tags: android, parsing

Hi I'm testing on encryption & decryption of a web url &  trying to develop intent to web browser.

```
String decrypted = DecodeAES.decrypt(AESkey, encrypted);
decryptedValue.setText(decrypted);
```

here i want to retrieve "decryptedValue" and to be placed in the Uri.parse
actually here the "decryptedValue" contains some website to be opened in webbrowser.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Please tell me how to use Uri.parse & what to be used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the uri need protocol, this case, is http://www.google.com, http is the protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change -

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
```

to -

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: the thing is i want to parse text to string. that means here 'decryptValue'=http://www.google.com

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse('decryptValue'));

Comment: So it can be - `Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + decryptValue));`